# Editing custom types in property grid

Tags: c#

I have a class `MinMax` which among other things contains this:

```
public class MinMax
{
    private float m_min = 0;
    private float m_max = 1;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return m_min + " " + m_max;
    }
}
```

I also have another class `SomeClass` with a property of this type:

```
public MinMax Something
{
    get
    {
        return m_something;
    }
    set
    {
        m_something = value;
    }
}
```

When I put an object of type `SomeClass` in a property grid, `Something` is correctly displayed but for natural reasons I'm not able to edit the value.

I know I can create a custom type editor and show a custom form to edit it, but I would like to edit the displayed string directly.

My first solution was to return a `string` from `Something` instead but I have other code that needs this property to be returned in it's native format.

Is thera any other convenient solution that will let med edit the value directly as a string in the propertygrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for a Custom `UITypeEditor`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx

For completeness have a look also to `TypeConverter`,
that can be used to allow simple editing (e.g. from-to strings) without the need of a custom `UITypeEditor`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Comment: It looks like a type converter is what I need, if I create a type converter `MinMaxConverter` which can convert a string to a `MinMax` and add something like `[TypeConverter(typeof(MinMaxConverter))]` to my `Something` property will things automatically work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... yes of course you can also use only `TypeConverter`, but in case you need a more complicated editing (e.g. if string is not enough), `UITypeEditor` suits perfectly.